# iOS UILabel blurry after UIPinchGesture

Tags: ios, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer, blurry

I have a UIView in my ViewController that users can move around the screen, rotate and zoom in and out. All with UIGestureRecognizers.

The problem I have is that the UIView contains a UILabel and after zooming the label is very blurry.

Here is the code for the zoom:

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer : UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    recognizer.view!.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view!.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale)
    recognizer.scale = 1
}
```

Also, when the user leaves the screen I am saving the new location and transformation of the UIView like this:

```
func saveViewValues() {
    var userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(NSStringFromCGPoint(self.theView.center), forKey:kViewCenter)
    userDefaults.setObject(NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.theView.transform), forKey:kViewTransform)
    userDefaults.synchronize()
}
```

This way when I reload the page I can use these values to reset the UIView to how the user last had it.

All works fine however the UILabel is very blurry if the user zooms in on the view.

Is there a way I can make the text crisp, even when zoomed? And how do I save this value like the others so that it can be put back afterwards and be crisp straight away?

Hope this makes sense.